# Identify matching key in Laravel Scout

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout

I'm using Laravel Scout with TNTSearch. Is there any way to ascertain which fields (array keys on the `toSearchableArray()` method) have been matched when a result is returned by the `search` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since TNTSearch is field agnostic it isn't possible to know which field was matched.

Comment: Sad :( They could put a reference to the full length token to each sub-token, so the reference would be there